# Killing a server-side process in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api, google-colab

This is probably a newbie error, but I've created an Export to Drive task in a for loop using the Python API in Colab that is ridiculously huge. It keeps downloading data to my drive, even after I've shut Colab. I had somehow excepted that killing my Colab runtime would stop all server-side processes in Earth Engine. I was wrong.

How do I kill these processes? Will they get killed if I just let my drive fill up?

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out: use the Earth engine command line tool: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/command_line

It let's user access and manage assets and tasks.  Install the Python API, authenticate your GEE account and run this script to delete batches of blunders...

```
import os
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen

blunders=30
command = 'earthengine task list'
with Popen(command, stdout=PIPE, stderr=None, shell=True) as process:
    output = process.communicate()[0].decode("utf-8")
    print(output)
    
output=output.splitlines()   
for c in range(blunders):
    command ='earthengine task cancel '+output[c][0:24]
    os.system(command)
```